# Ignore /page/ part of HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with /page/ part when using JQuery.

I have an if who checks sites link (`link.get(0).href`) with anchor tag link(`location.href`).
For example [www.test.com/](http://test.com/) = `<a href="www.test.com/"></a>`

Everything works fine, but after i switch to 2nd page [www.test.com/page/2](http://test.com/page/2) site link doesn't match anchor tag link, so is there a way to ignore this /page/2 part?

Here is the function :

```
        var link = $(this);
        var url = link.get(0).href;

        if (url === location.href) {
            link.addClass("red").parents(".active").addClass("red");
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `location.host` to get host only. Or check is `location.href` contains links `href` width

```
~location.href.indexOf(href)
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. Have to smoke this out, probobly this is the answerd i need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anton, got this with indexOF()

```
if (location.href.indexOf(url) == -1) {
} else {
  link.addClass("woocommerce-menu-cat-color").parents(".active").addClass("woocommerce-menu-cat-color");
}
```